# Insert two row in wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Hello I am working on a template where I have to grab some value and insert them in my own created table in wordpress database.
Now as I dont know how to insert record in wordpress database , so i am trying it on my local server for practice.
my temlate file is:

```
<?php
/**
   Template Name: Injection.
 */
get_header();
?>
<form method="post" action="">
Album: <input type="text" name="album" />
Artist: <input type="text" name="artist" />
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
 global $wpdb

 $album=$_POST['album'];
 $artist=$_POST['artist'];

 $wpdb->insert( 'music', array( 'album' => $album, 'artist' => $artist ), array( '%s', '%s' ) )
}
?>
```

and here I have a strange problem If I dont use $wbdb class here then my temlate file data show on front end but when I used $wpdb for insertion then it show nothing on front end.

So do you have any suggestion for what should I do for Insert data in mysql.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not add ; sign in your template, try something like below code.

```
    <?php
/**
   Template Name: Injection.
 */
get_header();
?>
<form method="post" action="">
Album: <input type="text" name="album" />
Artist: <input type="text" name="artist" />
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
 global $wpdb;

 $album=$_POST['album'];
 $artist=$_POST['artist'];

 $wpdb->insert( 'music', array( 'album' => $album, 'artist' => $artist ), array( '%s', '%s' ) );
}
?>
```

Comment: Actually I checked it many times and page itself did not giving any parse erroe, but know it working and i successfully saved data in table.... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"show nothing on front end.". I think there's something wrong with php, to find out what the error is, try this:

edit wp-config.php, make WP_DEBUG true.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Now it's supposed to see some error messages on the front page.

Answer (score 0):

First open the theme / function.php file and add this code into function.php file.
First add the hook_action().

```
 add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','save_to_db');
```

now create the function for store data in to the database.

```
    function save_to_db($cf7) {

       global $wpdb;

       $name = $_POST["your-name"];
       $mail = $_POST["your-email"];
       $subject = $_POST["your-subject"];
       $phoneno = $_POST["your-phoneno"];
       $address = $_POST["your-address"];
       $message = $_POST["your-message"];

       $test = $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'contactus', 
        array(
          'name'          => 'test',
          'email'       => 'test@gmail.com',
          'subject'     => 'fsaf',
          'phone'       => '1234566230',
          'address'     => 'tes',
          'message'     => 'asdasdasd'            
        ),
        array(
          '%s',
          '%s',
          '%s',
          '%s',
          '%s',
          '%s'
        ) 
       ); 
       /*echo $wpdb->last_query;die;
      echo '<pre>'; print_r($test);*/
    }
```

Comment: Could you also add some context / explanation?

Comment: I have added some context. please check it. Its working in any condition,